# Is there a known issue with Safari-8 and WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, safari, websocket, osx-yosemite, safari8

I've installed the Yosemite preview and WebSockets don't work for me on Safari 8.

The [echo test page](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) works on Chrome (with the secure checkbox set) but when I try with Safari it fails silently.

I debugged the page and what happens is that the WebSocket is created but its `onopen` event is not fired and the socket's `readyState` [status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Ready_state_constants) remains stuck on `CONNECTING` (0).

I couldn't find any references to this problem, is there any configuration I may have missed that causes/fixes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari has updated (to version 8.0.10600.1.22) and the problem is now resolved.